# Получение элемента из QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

QTableWidgetУсловие: Создать квадратную матрицу. Матрица должна содержать слова из 4х букв английского алфавита. Из каждого слова удалить все гласные буквы. На основе измененной матрицы сформировать массив, состоящий из размеров строк матрицы, который необходимо упорядочить по убыванию.

Не могу понять каким образом реализовать удаление гласных букв в QtableWidget (желательно по кнопке), буду благодарен за любые наводки!

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

int elements;
QString alphavit = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_start_clicked()
{
    QString line;
    elements = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
    if (elements >= 2 && elements <= 5) {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(elements);
        ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(elements);
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < elements; j++)
            {

                ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, j, new QTableWidgetItem(""));
            }
        }
    }



    else {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(0);
        ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(0);
        ui->label->setText("Размер матрицы должен быть от 2 до 5");
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_random_clicked()
{
    QString end = "";
    int r;
    QString simv;
    for (int i=0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < elements; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                r = rand() % 26;
                simv = alphavit.at(r);
                end = end + simv;
            }
            QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem (end, 10);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,j,item);
            end.clear();
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_cellChanged(int row, int column)
{
    QString s = ui->tableWidget->item(row, column)->text();
    if (s.isEmpty()) return;
    if (!alphavit.contains(s.at(0))) {
        ui->label->clear();
        ui->label->setText("Вводите только английские слова");
        QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem ("", 10);
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,column,item);
        return;
    }
    if (!(s.length() == 4)) {
        ui->label->clear();
        ui->label->setText("Вводите только 4-х буквенные английские слова");
        QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem ("", 10);
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,column,item);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Не могу понять каким образом реализовать удаление гласных букв в QtableWidget (желательно по кнопке)`... А в чем именно проблема? В кнопке? В получении элемента QTableWidget? В самом алгоритме удаления гласных букв из строки?

Comment: В получении элемента.

Comment: тогда было бы неплохо соответствующим образом изменить вопрос или заголовок поста, т.к. "задача на матрицу" звучит недостаточно информативно

Comment: Исправил заголовок.

Comment: а вообще, значение ячейки можно получить при помощи номера строки и столбца следующим образом: `ui->tableWidget->item(i, j)->text()`. Причем у Вас в коде уже есть такая строка (в функции `on_tableWidget_cellChanged(int row, int column)`)

Comment: Мне нужно по кнопке сделать, после заполненный матрицы, а если делать в Cell Changed, он сразу будет удалять гласные буквы.

Comment: Ну, тогда реализуйте алгоритм в обработчике другой кнопки. Всего-то нужно пройтись циклом по всем элементам, получить текущее значение при помощи `item(i, j)-text()`, удалить гласные, установить новые значения с помощью `item(i, j)->setText(value)`. В чем именно трудность?

Comment: `QString vowels = "aeyuio";
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < elements; j++)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem* item = ui->tableWidget->item(i,j);
            if (item != NULL)
            {
                QString s = item->text();
                if (s.isEmpty()) return;
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < vowels.length(); i1++)
                {
                    s = s.replace(vowels.at(i1),"");
                }
                item->setText(s);
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Вот, попробовал сделать, нажимаю на кнопку - ничего не происходит.

Comment: а нажатие кнопки связано с обработчиком?

Comment: Немного непонимающе, можете показать пример?

Comment: `void MainWindow::on_pushbutton_deletevowels_clicked() {}`

Comment: если вы создали кнопку вручную, то нужно вручную в конструкторе делать `connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot)`, или как вариант пересоздать обработчик из дизайнера (ПКМ на кнопке -> перейти к слоту -> clicked... как-то так), но это уже не относится к теме поста

Comment: Спасибо Bogdan, заработало. Только он удаляет всю строку, а не только гласные буквы.

Comment: Все, спасибо большое за помощь. Все работает, разобрался.